# How to embed a Github Repo Insight page to a new Google Site?

Tags: github, google-classic-sites

I have a private "new google site" where I would like to have an overview of several metrics. One of them is the number of open PRs on a private repository in Github.

I can insert an embed github page if it is public (https://github.com/ for example) but when I try to embed a private page (https://github.com/mygroup/myrepo/pulse for the insight of my private repo for example) I get:

> Can't embed due to provider site permissions. URL will display as a text link.

But my session is logged in on github (i.e. I can access the link if I click on it).

Is there a way to embed the insights page directly?